# MySQL: using calculated counter column as key for sub-query

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Sorry, long pre-history, but it is needed to clarify the question.

In my org the computers have names like `CNT30[0-9]{3}[1-9a-z]`, for example `cnt300021` or `cnt30253a`.

Last symbol is a "qualifier", so single workplace may have equally named computers assigned to it, distinguished by this qualifier. For example `cnt300021` may mean desktop computer on workplace #002, and `cnt30002a` may mean notebook assigned for same workplace. Workplaces are "virtual" and their existence made just for our (IT dept) convenience.

Each dept have its own unique range `[0-9]{3}`. For example, computers of accounting have names starting `cnt302751` upto `cnt30299z` which gives them 25 unique workplaces max, with up to 35 computers per workplace. (IRL most users have one desktop PC, much lesser have desktop and notebook, and only 2 or 3 technicians have more than one notebook at their disposal).

Recently, doing some inventory of computers' passports *(unsure about a term: a paper, which means for computer the same, what a passport means for human),* I found that there some holes in sequential numbering. For example, we have `cnt302531` and `cnt302551`, but have no `cnt302541`, which means that there's no workplace #254.

What I want to do? I want to find these gaps without manual searching. For this I need a cycle from 1 to `MaxComp=664` (no more workplace numbers assigned yet)

That's what I could write using some pseudo-SQL-BASIC:

```vb
for a=0 to MaxComp
  a$="CNT30"+right(a+1000,3)
'comparing only 8 leftmost characters, ignoring 9th one - the qualifier
  b$=(select name from table where left(name,8) like a$)
  print a$;b$
next a
```

That code should give me two columns: possible names and existing ones.

But I can't figure out how to implement this in a SQL query. What I tried:

```sql
# because of qualifier there may be several computers with same
# 8 leftmost characters
select @cnum:=@cnum+1 as CompNum, group_concat(name separator ',')
# PCs are inventoried by OCS-NG Inventory software
  from hardware
  cross join (select @cnum:=0) cnt
  where left(hardware.name,8)=concat('CNT30',right(@cnum+1000,3))
  limit 100
```

But this construct returns exactly one row. And I can't understand, if it is possible without using the stored procedures, and what I did wrong if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found working path:

(at first I tried to use stored function)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `count_comps`(num smallint) RETURNS tinytext CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    return (select group_concat(name separator ',')
        from hardware where left(hardware.name,8)=concat('CNT30',right(num+1000,3))
        );
END
```

Then I tried hard to replicate function's results in subquery. And I did it! Note: the inner select returns exactly same results as function does

```sql
# Starting point. May be INcreased to narrow the results list
set @cnum:=0;
select
    @cnum:=@cnum+1 as CompNum,
    concat('CNT30',right(@cnum+1000,3)) as CalcNum,
# this
    count_comps(@cnum) as hwns,
# and this gives equal results
    (select group_concat(name separator ',')
        from hardware where left(name,8)=calcnum
        ) hwn2
    from hardware
# no more dummy tables here
# Ending point. May be DEcreased to narrow the results list
  where @cnum<665;
```

So, the wrong part of "classical" approach was the usage of dummy table, which seems to be not necessary.

Partial results example (starting `set @cnum:=479;`, finishing `where @cnum<530;`):

`CompNum, CalcNum, hwns, hwn2
'488', 'CNT30488', 'CNT304881', 'CNT304881'
'489', 'CNT30489', 'CNT304892', 'CNT304892'
'490', 'CNT30490', 'CNT304901,CNT304902,CNT304903', CNT304901,CNT304902,CNT304903'
'491', 'CNT30491', NULL, NULL
'492', 'CNT30492', NULL, NULL
'493', 'CNT30493', 'CNT304932', 'CNT304932'
'494', 'CNT30494', 'CNT304941', 'CNT304941'`

I found that there no workplaces #491 and #492. On next adding the PCs for the 'October Region' dept (range 480-529), at least two of new PCs will get names CNT304911 and CNT304921, filling this gap.